# Elasticsearch - count word occurrences in all texts from index

Tags: python, elasticsearch, full-text-search

I need to get a count of word X from all texts in index Y, which has only one field "content". Note that I need a count of specific word, how many times it occurred in total across all documents. From what I've found ES is not well optimized for this (since this is a text type), but this is for university homework, so I have little choice.

So far I've tried (taken from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45617814/elasticsearch-count-of-matches-per-document/55943306)):

```
{
  "script_fields": {
    "phrase_Count": {
      "script": {
        "lang": "painless",
        "source": "int count = 0; if(doc['content.keyword'].size() > 0 && doc['content'].value.indexOf(params.phrase)!=-1) count++; return count;",
        "params": {
          "phrase": "ustawa"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

The scripting approach returns:

```
{
  "error": {
    "root_cause": [
      {
        "type": "script_exception",
        "reason": "runtime error",
        "script_stack": [
          "org.elasticsearch.search.lookup.LeafDocLookup.get(LeafDocLookup.java:88)",
          "org.elasticsearch.search.lookup.LeafDocLookup.get(LeafDocLookup.java:40)",
          "if(doc['content.keyword'].size() > 0 && doc['content'].value.indexOf(params.phrase)!=-1) ",
          "       ^---- HERE"
        ],
        "script": "int count = 0; if(doc['content.keyword'].size() > 0 && doc['content'].value.indexOf(params.phrase)!=-1) count++; return count;",
        "lang": "painless",
        "position": {
          "offset": 22,
          "start": 15,
          "end": 104
        }
      }
    ],
    "type": "search_phase_execution_exception",
    "reason": "all shards failed",
    "phase": "query",
    "grouped": true,
    "failed_shards": [
      {
        "shard": 0,
        "index": "bills",
        "node": "MXtcD7-zT-mhDyxMeRTMLw",
        "reason": {
          "type": "script_exception",
          "reason": "runtime error",
          "script_stack": [
            "org.elasticsearch.search.lookup.LeafDocLookup.get(LeafDocLookup.java:88)",
            "org.elasticsearch.search.lookup.LeafDocLookup.get(LeafDocLookup.java:40)",
            "if(doc['content.keyword'].size() > 0 && doc['content'].value.indexOf(params.phrase)!=-1) ",
            "       ^---- HERE"
          ],
          "script": "int count = 0; if(doc['content.keyword'].size() > 0 && doc['content'].value.indexOf(params.phrase)!=-1) count++; return count;",
          "lang": "painless",
          "position": {
            "offset": 22,
            "start": 15,
            "end": 104
          },
          "caused_by": {
            "type": "illegal_argument_exception",
            "reason": "No field found for [content.keyword] in mapping with types []"
          }
        }
      }
    ]
  },
  "status": 400
}
```

Above the `content.keyword` was used, since with plain `content` ES was complaining about the text type not being optimized for such searches.

I also tried using text statistics (from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42019940/how-to-get-term-vector-info-for-the-whole-index-in-elastic-search-not-at-a-doc)), but I couldn't get this to work, it only counted documents with the word (which is not what I'm looking for).

As my last approach I tried search with aggregation (from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29842092/elasticsearch-count-frequency-of-occurrence-of-a-set-of-words-in-a-set-of-docum?fbclid=IwAR0cnNuBrOFrLYSj1tZ9H3gcbONrxp2cf6VYSvQKq5K03QPkUegXaAJkdyc)), but it also just returned the count of documents, not words:

```
{
  "query": {
    "query_string": {
      "fields": ["content"],
      "query": "ustawa"
    }
  },  
  "aggs": {
    "my-terms": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "content.keyword"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

How can I achieve this? I'm using Python, if it matters.

**EDIT**
Mapping for index I'm using:

```
  "mappings": {
    "properties": {
      "content": {
        "type": "text",
        "analyzer": "my_analyzer"
      }
    }
  }
```

Comment: Can you include the index mapping in your post? The error seems to occur when trying to access the `content.keyword` field, does this field exist? It could look like this `"content": { ..., "fields": { "keyword": {...}}}`

Comment: @OnnoRouast I've added the mapping. I've added the `.keyword`, since the Elasticsearch was suggesting it in the error message.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a build in API in Elasticsearch to retrieve such information, since document and term frequency are very relevant for the BM25 scoring in Elasticsearch. See the [Term vectors API](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/docs-termvectors.html) and the [term statistics](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/docs-termvectors.html#docs-termvectors-api-term-stats) option. You are looking for the "**total term frequency**" value there.

If you only want to return the term statistics for specific terms and not all terms in existing documents, you can send an "[**artifical document**](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/docs-termvectors.html#docs-termvectors-artificial-doc)" to the api that only contains the terms you are looking for.

Comment: I've seen it, it looks promising, but I had little success with it. Is it possible to filter out just one word with it, instead of getting counts for all words? Also I think I need to know an ID of any document containing the word that I'm looking for and query it to get the count?

Comment: You can send an "artifical document" to the api that only contains the terms you are looking for: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/docs-termvectors.html#docs-termvectors-artificial-doc

Comment: This is exactly what I'm looking for! Could you mention it in the answer, so I can accept it?

Answer (score 3):

In the Elasticsearch 7.11 anonsed runtime_mappings. With this feature you could build new field in runtime and after that count the words in all your documents with regular "sum" aggregation.

For example:

```
PUT test/_doc/1
{
  "field" : "test test test ss"

}
PUT test/_doc/2
{
  "field" : "test test test ss"

}
GET test/_search
{
  "size": 0, 
  "runtime_mappings": {
    "phrase_count": {
      "type": "long",
      "script": """
         String tmp = doc['field.keyword'].value;
         Matcher m = /(test)/.matcher(tmp);
         int count = 0;
         while (m.find()){
           count++;
         }
         emit(count);
          """
    }
  },
  "query": {
    "match_all": {}
  }, 
  "aggs": {
    "word_count": {
      "sum": {
        "field": "phrase_count"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

The "test" in the Matcher - word, that you looking for and want to count.