# Counting the SEARCH term/phrase in a specific field in Elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch, search, kibana

I have this type of data

```json
{
    "name_id": 2145
    "address": "Antartica"
    "characteristics" : "He is a very nice person with very nice personality. the nicest thing about him is his nice dog"
}
```

now I am running this query

```json
GET friends/_search
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {"term": {
          "name_id.keyword": "B08F2BWX2V"
        }
        },
        {
          "match_phrase": {
            "characteristics": "nice"
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

is there a way i can get the results and the word count i.e,
nice : 4

Answer (score 0):

There is an elastic api that can return the token count information you need.
It is the [Term vectors API](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/docs-termvectors.html).
I'm not sure if it will be exactly what you need but I saw in the post below a question similar to yours:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/69734423/18778181

Comment: is there a way to get through _search api