# Sort by search phrase occurrences count Elasticsearch

Tags: php, sorting, elasticsearch

I want to sort by occurrences count in Elasticsearch.

For example, I have some texts that contain **Ludwig van Beethoven** string and I want to sort them by these string occurrences count in the text.

Is this possible?

Comment: I think this is what you are looking for : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69730079/elasticsearch-count-word-occurrences-in-all-texts-from-index

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Elasticsearch - count word occurrences in all texts from index](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69730079/elasticsearch-count-word-occurrences-in-all-texts-from-index)